# How to set 2checkout payment timeout?

Tags: api, integration, 2checkout

I'm currently integrating into 2co.
Before redirecting the client to 2co checkout page, I book the goods in my system for a moment(10 minutes) and they are not available for this period for other clients. After the time elapsed, they'll be auto unbooked.

But at this moment do I have any influence on the payment process which actually is going on in parallel in another place? From what I've read, I only receive the info about the result of payment when the user(client) has successfully(or not) finished his work.

Is there any timeout parameters I can set before the payment or special links I can refer in the case of timeout occured?

Comment: one of the workarounds I see is to call 2co refund invoice script, but the disadvantage is that I loose the commission fee I've paid for transaction.

Comment: I wonder if there is a regular way to achieve the result, because it's normal to lock the amount of goods in DB and release it after being sure that the client has forgotten about the order or has ignored it for some reason. Otherwise all the goods become locked soon by any unfair person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2Checkout transaction fees are not taken from the sale until it deposits (settles). When selling intangible products or using the third party cart parameter set, the sale will not deposit for at least 24 hours. If you are selling tangible products with the Pass Through Product parameters or Plug and Play parameters, the sale will not deposit until you mark it as shipped.

The buyer's 2Checkout purchase session will expire after 60 minutes. So you could pass in your custom cart identifier using 2Checkout's `merchant_order_id` parameter, release the booking after any time interval you choose and if the buyer completes the sale after the booking has been released, decide whether or not you want to refund using the [refund_invoice API call](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/api/) based on the cart identifier passed back from 2Checkout with the `merchant_order_id` parameter.

As far as handling the passback, you can either use the initial passback to your approved URL that occurs when the sale is completed, or you can use the [2Checkout Instant Notification Service Order Created message](https://www.2checkout.com/static/va/documentation/INS/index.html). If you use the ORDER_CREATED message from the INS, the value you pass in with the `merchant_order_id` will be passed back using the `vendor_order_id` parameter on all INS messages pertaining to the sale.

Let me know if you would like some help implementing this.

Comment: One thing that is not clear using `refund_invoice` call. From the customer's point of view, what it will be like? Having paid the deal he then gets the money back, the deal is done and canceled after? 
Will it take a certain period of time the process of returning him the spent money?

Comment: Since you will be issuing the refund before the sale deposits, the customer will never be charged. The customer will have a pending authorization hold on their card which will fall off with in 7 days of placing the order and the transaction will not reflect on their statement. 2Checkout will also send the customer an email confirmation with the reason for the refund and the comment that you specified when making the `refund_invoice` call.

Comment: Exhaustingly! Thank you ever so much.

Comment: @Craig-2Checkout how can we use [java library](https://github.com/2Checkout/2checkout-java) for android